# Array element assignment in Google (Apps) Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I'm associating a Google (Apps) Script with a Google Spreadsheet.

The entire script works except for the following line:

```
headers[0] = headers[0] + ":";
```

Removing this line allows the script to run. Adding it makes it fail.

The array is initialized beforehand as follows.

```
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
```

What's wrong with my element assignment, and how do I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The very simple test function:

```
function whenOpen() {  
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var headers = s.getRange(1,1,1,s.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  Logger.log('Array of headers: ' + headers);
  Logger.log('First header: ' + headers[0]);
  headers[0] = headers[0] + ":";
  Logger.log('Modified header: ' + headers[0]);
}
```

Runs perfectly for me: http://prntscr.com/58a6fx

I don't get any errors, so I suspect the issue is more complex then this one line, as it does not appear to be the culprit. If you try it yourself in a fresh script (Bound to a spreadsheet, with some values in the headers, ofc), it should run with issue.